# What is your recommended PHP/MySQL user registration system?

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I am looking for a turn-key, reliable and secure user registration system. It must be PHP/MySQL. I would like to have features such as "remember me", password retrieval and email validation.

Does such a script exist? I have been trying to write one, but I am a newby and think that if I could see how one works, then it would help me learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be contributing to yet needing to remember another set of [login credentials(probably unsafe too)](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/12/the-dirty-truth-about-web-passwords.html). Please use something like openid, google friend connect, facebook connect, etc. I created a [small library](https://github.com/alfredwesterveld/php-openid) which uses lightopenid. It is just forking project and you are good to go. Store the unique url inside a session(prevent session-fixation).

You should be able to view demo at a small domain of mine: http://westerveld.name/php-openid/. The only thing I did was cloning the project from github.

Comment: This is way better than the road I was going down. Thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: no problem. Thank you for agreeing with me on this ;). If you put myopenid affialate link(https://www.myopenid.com/affiliate) in it then it also going to be very user-friendly in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Facebook Connect.  It is widespread in use and isn't going anywhere, plus it will allow for a very large portion of your user base to skip a registration step altogether - if they already have a Facebook account, they are already registered.

Comment: There is a caveat: if they DON'T have a Facebook account, they'll either a) have to register on Facebook, which some people have a problem with, or b) you'll have to give them your own option.  So, Facebook Connect isn't a silver bullet in this case.  However, you could implement a highly rudimentary login script based of one of the large number of tutorials around on the internet, with Facebook being your primary mechanism.  Something like this: http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at Drupal. You might wrap your whole site inside a Drupal frame, or you might just look at the source code and see how they did it.

Comment: I think you are right. The more I look at solutions, and try them, along with the hours of work that comes along with it, this should have been my first choice.